# Metadata version mismatch for module using angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

when I try to type the command "npm start". I got this error :

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/zack/Desktop/projects/my_project/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/zack/Desktop/projects/my_project/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/zack/Desktop/projects/my_project/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/zack/Desktop/projects/my_project/src/app/app.module.ts
```

[image]

I really don't know what causing the issue. I have install earlier @angular/cdk and @angular/material to its latest version by hoping it will fix the problem but it isn't.

Below is my dependencies from package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngtools/json-schema": "^1.1.0",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "^3.1.0",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "angular2-ladda": "^1.2.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-notifications-lite": "^0.1.2",
    "common-tags": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.3",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng-block-ui": "^0.9.2",
    "ng2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-file-drop": "^1.1.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-file-uploader": "^0.1.4",
    "ng2-inputmask": "^0.2.5",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.11",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "ngx-gallery": "^3.1.3",
    "ngx-quill": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "swagger-js-codegen": "^1.10.1",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Comment: post your app.module.ts and package.json

Comment: One of your dependencies is dependent on angular5, others are dependent on angular4. To fix this, find the package that's causing the issue and downgrade angular.

Comment: @pixelbits what package you mean?

Comment: all your packages listed in package.json

Comment: is any error in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @sack I thought @pixelbits meaning is stable version is not supported angular 4 ~ before(`cdk` and `material`).

Comment: @RachChen I'm not sure if the error is coming from app.module.ts You can see the error I post from the above of this post